# Unable to pastebin using curl on the command line: Bad API request, invalid api_option

Tags: php, curl, pastebin

I'm trying to create a paste using curl like this:

```
$ url="http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php"
$ headers="Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"
$ data="api_option=paste&api_dev_key=<my-key-here>&api_paste_code=testing&api_option=paste"
$ curl -X POST -H "$headers" --data "$data" $url
```

but instead of getting back the url of my paste I get the error in the title of this posting

honestly, I'm astounded that there don't seem to be any reasonable solutions out there for pastebinning from the OSX command line.

*** Update I ***

by ways of comparison, this small PHP script works fine:

```
<?
$ch = curl_init('http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php');
$api_dev_key = '<my-key-here>';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'api_option=paste&api_dev_key='.$api_dev_key.'&api_paste_code=testing');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

echo curl_exec($ch) . "\n";
?>
```

so what's different?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have the header incorrect. It should be:

```
$ headers="Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
```

Comment: it did something... now I get the error "Bad API request, invalid api_dev_key" instead